# What is `<map object at 0x02937190>` on python lambda function output?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm new to python lambda functions. So this question maybe a dummy one. I have the following sample code in python:

```py
halve_evens_only = lambda nums: map(lambda i: i/2, filter(lambda i: not i%2, nums))
```

by calling this function like `halve_evens_only([2,5,7,89,36])` I got the following output:

```
<map object at 0x02937190>
```

Is that a generator? How can I get the value ( I mean a list ) as an output of this function?

Comment: Yes, that is a generator. You'll have to iterate over it to get its contents. Calling `list()` on it will work.

Comment: It's an *iterator*. Generators are a specific kind of iterator.

Comment: When you want a list out `map` it's generally cleaner to use a list comprehension.

Comment: I am getting the output `<function <lambda> at 0x7f7de21f31f0>`. How are you getting `<map object at 0x02937190>`

Comment: @PaulRooney: Especially in this case, where they're also using `filter`, and a listcomp could combine both operations into one. What they wrote could simplify to (and make an actual `list` in the process) `[i / 2 for i in nums if not i % 2]` (or `i // 2` to avoid conversion to `float`, which seems like the right idea given the division will be lossless).

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's exactly what I was about to suggest.

Comment: This is one of the contentious differences between Python 2 and Python 3.  In Python2, `map` returns a list.  In Python3, it returns an iterator, and as others have pointed out, you need to use `list(map(.....))` to get what you want.  Check if your the text you're using to learn Python from is for Python2 or Python3.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, that's what I meant. It was late, I was tired...

Answer (score -1):

As you know Python is an object-oriented language. The output from `lambda` is stored as an object at that particular memory location.
To print the output, you need to specify a datatype.

Let's say you specify `list()`.
Then the output generated by the lambda function will be put in a list and presented at the output.

You can also specify any other datatype depending on the operation performed.

Comment: It returns the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: I don't think this will work. You are passing a lambda to `list`. I think what you want to do is pass the result of calling the lambda to `list`.

Comment: It's not that "you need to specify a datatype". The object already has a type. You're not specifying one. `list(...)` *calls* `list`, and `list` iterates over its argument and adds the retrieved items to a new list.